# How many days deleted posts(either questions or answers) visible in my profile?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

how many posts does recently deleted questions or answers tab stores?
is there any time limit for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shows your deleted posts, posted the last 60 days.

From [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/229438):

> Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days.

Comment: where did you find this answer?

Comment: @SagarPudi I added that to my answer.